# How to get data from webservice in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I have a web service with link: `http://41.128.183.109:9090/api/data/getalllocations`

I recived this data in dropdown using jquery .this data contains 2 objects `LocationName` and `LocID`. I want to display an alert with `LocID` in dropdown change function in jQuery. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Get',
        url: 'http://41.128.183.109:9090/api/data/getalllocations',
        success: function (data) {
            var SubDropdown = $("#main");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                SubDropdown.append('<option value?' + i + '?="">' + data[i].LocationName + '</option>');
            }
        }
    });
});

$("#countries").change(function () {
    alert();
});
```

Here is my HTML code :

```
<select tabindex="-1" class="select2_group form-control" style="display: normal; width: 290px;" name="countries" id="countries">
    <optgroup label="Select Your City" id="main"></optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: You need to describe better what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try following

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Get',
        url: 'http://41.128.183.109:9090/api/data/getalllocations',
        success: function (data) {
            var SubDropdown = $("#main");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                SubDropdown.append('<option value="' + data[i].LocID + '">' + data[i].LocationName + '</option>');
            }
        }
    });

    $("#countries").change(function () {
        alert($("#countries").val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Weird... now exactly the same as my answer, but I got a downvote... Hmmmm

Comment: I want to display location name in dropdown  . but when  alert i want to display LocID  . Can I do this .